# apply set() to remove duplicates in a list inside a tuple - Python

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a RDD key/value pair where value is a list like this:
my RDD is like this

```
[("a1",["w1","w2","w3","w1"]), ("a2",["w3","w3","w3","w1"]), ....
```

how I can apply the function set, only to the list element to remove the duplicates?

I have this so far but not getting the correct results:

```
uniqueTokens = RDD.map(lambda x: (x[0],set(x[1])))
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Please show what you get, compared to what you are expecting.

Comment: I have this RDD: [("a1",["w1","w2","w3","w1"]), ("a2",["w3","w3","w3","w1"]),... 
And want this:   [("a1",["w1","w2","w3"), ("a2",["w3","w1"]) each pair should not have duplicates

Comment: To Pythonistas who are unfamiliar with RDD: https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/api/core/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html

Comment: Your code works as expected for me in pySpark 1.4.1:

    rdd = sc.parallelize([("a1",["w1","w2","w3","w1"]), ("a2",["w3","w3","w3","w1"])])
    uniqueTokens = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0],set(x[1])))
    print(uniqueTokens.collect())

Output: 
    [('a1', set(['w3', 'w2', 'w1'])), ('a2', set(['w3', 'w1']))]

Answer (score 2):

Unique items of each list in rdd `[("a1",["w1","w2","w3","w1"]), ("a2",["w3","w3","w3","w1"]), ....` such as: `(w1, w2, w3, w3, w1,...)`.You can use `set()` inside a `flatMap()`:

```
RDD.flatMap(lambda x: set(x[1]))
>> (w1, w2, w3, w3, w1,...)

#if you want to get unique items in each list and total counts across whole rdd
RDD.flatMap(lambda x: set(x[1]))
   .map(lambda x: (x , 1))
   .reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y ).collect()
>> [(w1, 2), (w2, 1), (w3, 2)]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Is it possible to do this with dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [48]: lt
Out[48]: [('a1', ['w1', 'w2', 'w3', 'w1']), ('a2', ['w3', 'w3', 'w3', 'w1'])]

In [49]: [(x,set(y)) for (x,y) in lt]
Out[49]: [('a1', {'w1', 'w2', 'w3'}), ('a2', {'w1', 'w3'})]
```

Comment: didnt work remember I have a RDD , with key/value pair, and the value pair is a list